# How to use a variable for import video in React?

Tags: reactjs, audio, import

We have to import audio in react like this example:

```
import audio from './audio1.mp3';
```

But what can I do to use different path which I have in my object. How can I change audio1.mp3 path to audio2.mp3?

Comment: please elaborate your question, from what i understood you can create a array and assign values to variables like ==> [{audio : './audio.mp3'}, {name : './audio2.mp3}] and then map over it or access by index.

Comment: I don't have to assign value to variable. I need to change the import path from depending on the object

Comment: elaborate with your code.